# Dependence and Independence of set of functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space on over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\psi$ and $\phi$ be two linear functionals defined on $X$. Then, if $\ker(\phi)\subset \ker(\psi)$, can we have that the set $\{\phi, \psi\}$ is linearly dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *always* linearly dependent. That's trivial if one of them is $0$. Otherwise, take $v\in X$ such that $\phi(v)\neq0$. Let $\lambda=\psi(v)$ and consider the map $\psi-\lambda\phi$. Then, if $x\in X$, $x=x-\phi(x)v+\phi(x)v$, and $x-\phi(x)v\in\ker\phi$. Therefore, $x-\phi(x)v\in\ker\psi$ and\begin{align}\psi(x)&=\psi\bigl(x-\phi(x)v\bigr)+\psi\bigl(\phi(x)v\bigr)\\&=\lambda\phi(x).\end{align}So, $\psi-\lambda\phi=0$ and therefore $\psi$ and $\phi$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Do you want $\phi(v)=1$ (not $\phi(x)\ne 0$) and $\lambda=\psi(v)$?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos By "No, they can't", do you mean the set can't be linearly dependent? But you just proved it they are linearly dependent. And how do we get $x-\phi(x)v \in \ker(\phi)$? And do you mean if one of them is $0$, they are linearly dependent?

Comment: My mistake. I wrote what I wrote under the impression that the question actaually was “ can we have that the set $\{\phi,\psi\}$ is linearly independent?”

Comment: @José Carlos Santos  Ok. But how can we get/assume that $x-\phi(x)v\in \ker(\phi)$?

Comment: $\phi\bigl(x-\phi(x)v\bigr)=\phi(x)-\phi(x)\phi(v)=\phi(x)-\phi(x)=0$.